# Turn led on in function with different args. Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I can’t seem to wrap my head around how to do this. I tried searching but it just returns how to turn on a led with a raspberry pi. So here I am. I am trying to make a function so that I can check multiple values and if they match turn a led on. I guess my major issue is when it is true the led turns on, but if the next function shares the same led it will turn it off. If that makes sense.

```
# 

def turnon(led,x)
    if x == updating_x:
        turn led # from led, on

    else:
        turn led # from led, off

while True:

    #led 1
    turnon(1,20)

    #led 1
    turnon(1,50)

    #led 2
    turnon(2,10)
```

So say updating_x=20 so the led #1 would turn on but then the next function that has the same LED would turn it off. I thought about changing it to this

```
if x == updating_x:
    turn led # from led, on
    time.sleep()
    turn led off

else:
    pass
```

But it is somewhat time critical and I will want the multiple leds to turn on together and not just one after the other. I don’t want to get caught just sleeping if the value change true for another led.

FYI, the plan is 60ish leds with around 70 different check values

Any ideas on the right way to do this? and Thanks!

### Edit:

Sorry I will try and explain it better. So with the example I gave, I want led 1 to turn on if the update_x  == 20 or 50. (if update_x = 20 now) In the loop, it runs the first function which is true so the led turns on. But the second function will be false so it turns the led off, although it is still true for the first function.  The problem is that I want to keep the led on until the first function returns false.

Ignore the second bit with the time.sleep in it, just an idea but won't work for what I want.

writing this I had an idea of having the x variables I want to work in a list and using that list in the function parameters, if that works.  In the end there will be around 60 leds with about 5 values to turn each one on, 60 lists sounds like a pain.

Comment: If the `turnon` functions are mean't to be inside the `while` loop please edit indent it.

Comment: I'm afraid your pseudocode makes it so I have no idea what you're asking about. What exactly is the issue you're having, something to do with timing? I don't get it.